# Matching '_' and '-' in java regexes

Tags: java, regex

I had this regex in **java** that matched either an alphanumeric character or the tilde (~)

`^([a-z0-9])+|~$`

Now I have to add also the characters `-` and `_` I've tried a few combinations, neither of which work, for example:

`^([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+|~$`
`^([a-zA-Z0-9]|-|_)+|~$`

Sample input strings that must match:

woZOQNVddd

00000

ncnW0mL14-

dEowBO_Eu7

7MyG4XqFz-

A8ft-y6hDu
~

Any clues / suggestion?

Comment: Could you provide us some test samples? You solutions seem correct.

Comment: samples added. Note that I've added A-Z to match uppercase letters

Comment: God I hate regexes in java :@

Comment: If you take the time to learn them instead of just "trying a few combinations" they are not really that hard to learn. They are just a tiny programming language, much simpler than java or C. Spend just a few hours actually studying how they work, learn a few simple rules and you'll be doing them with your eyes closed by the end of the day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-` is a special character within square brackets. It indicates a range. If it's not at either end of the regex it needs to be escaped by putting a `\` before it.

It's worth pointing out a shortcut: `\w` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` so I think this is more readable:

```
^([\w-]+|~$
```

Comment: +1 - Somehow it had escaped (no pun intended) my notice that `\w` would also match an `_` character.  I guess that's so we can use it to match really bad variable names.

Comment: @Bill: it's often forgotten or either not known. It's a weird one. I think I'd prefer if that weren't the case because I've not used `\w` many times because of it but its easy to do `\w_` if you had to. And I think most of the time you don't care about `_`.

Comment: Note: `\w` might match way more than just ASCII in some RegEx flavors (not JavaScript, though). In some flavors it's more equivalent to `[\p{L}\p{N}_-]` (that is, matching any Unicode letter or number).

Comment: .NET, Perl, Tcl and a few others: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `-`, like `\-`, since it is a special character (the range operator).  `_` is ok.

So `^([a-z0-9_\-])+|~$`.

**Edit**: your last input String will not match because the regular expression you are using matches a string of alphanumeric characters (plus `-` and `_`) OR a tilde (because of the pipe).  But not both.  If you want to allow an optional tilde on the end, change to:

`^([a-z0-9_\-])+(~?)$`

Comment: Or you could put the dash as the first character which tells the parser not to consider it a range delimiter.

Comment: If it isn't throwing an error, and is just not matching, please post the input string.

Comment: I cannot group everything because I need either a number or just the tilde. If there's a tilde it must be the only character there

Comment: Ok, I moved that out.  Not sure where you want the - and _.  But if you're having problems, please post the input and observed behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If you put the `-` first, it won't be interpreted as the range indicator.

```
^([-a-zA-Z0-9_])+|~$
```

This matches all of your examples except the last one using the following code:

```
String str = "A8ft-y6hDu ~";
System.out.println("Result: " + str.matches("^([-a-zA-Z0-9_])+|~$"));
```

That last example won't match because it doesn't fit your description.  The regex will match any combination of alphanumerics, -, and _, OR a ~ character.

Comment: That's because I hadn't added the A-Z yet.  It matches now.

Comment: @Pablo: Yeah, I upvoted @cletus, since his answer is the one I would use, too. :)